# JavaScript dialog using AJAX call is out of sync

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, dialog

I'm having a problem with some JavaScript which is intended to display a JQUERY dialog box based on a C# ViewModel.

I have an ASP drop down within a repeater which displays 'Registration Date' information. The idea is when the user selects a date from the list, the JavaScript dialog box will appear displaying a more rounded summary of information relating to that registration using specific View Model properties. The function CustomerSummary is called on a standard  `$(document).ready` for the page in question.

**JS Code**

```
function CustomerSummary() {

    var registrationId;
    var data;

    $("select[id$='ddlRegistration']").change(function () {
        registrationId = $(this).val();

        if (registrationId !== 'default')
        {
            data = MakeAJAXCall(registrationId);
            $("#dialog").html("Registration Id: " + data.RegistrationId + "<br />" +
                               "Permit From: " + data.PermitFrom + "<br />" +
                               "Permit To: " + data.PermitTo + "<br />" +
                               "Registration Status: " + data.RegistrationStatus 
            );

            $("#dialog").dialog({

                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },

                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });
        }
    });

    function MakeAJAXCall(regId)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text json",
            url: "/Secure/CustomerSummary.aspx/GetRegistration",
            data: "{ regId: \"" + regId + "\" }",

            success: function (msg) {                
                data = msg.d;                
            },

            error: function (xOptions, textStatus)
            {                
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(xOptions);
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

**C# Code**

```
[WebMethod(), ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=false)]
        public static RegistrationViewModel GetRegistration(int regId)
        {            
            RegistrationRepository repo = new RegistrationRepository();
            RegistrationViewModel reg = new RegistrationViewModel();
            RegistrationFactory regFac = new RegistrationFactory();

            reg = regFac.ConvertToRegistrationViewModel(repo.GetRegistration(regId));

            return reg;
        }
```

**What is happening during debug**

What is happening here is on this line :

```
$("#dialog").html("Registration Id: " + data.RegistrationId + "<br />" +
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RegistrationId' of undefined
```

The first time I select a date from the menu and the change function is invoked, I get the above error message, and no dialog box appears, if I inspect `data` I can indeed see that it is undefined. Then, once I select a different data from the drop down menu, and I hit my breakpoint `(change.(function)` data is set to the data retrieved from the previous AJAX call, the dialog box then pops up but with the previous requests data, the results then stay in this cycle, every time I select a data I am presented with the previous selections information.

Can anyone point out why im constantly one selection out of sync, I believe its due to the first change request but I don't understand why the AJAX call isn't setting `data` to the desired result until I select the next drop down item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work

```
data = MakeAJAXCall(registrationId);
```

Because `MakeAJAXCall` is performing an Ajax call and it is asynchronous so the return will not execute in the same order as your return in the function. So, you need to use a callback.

Try this to change your code to something like:

```
MakeAJAXCall(registrationId, function(data){
 $("#dialog").html("Registration Id: " + data.RegistrationId + "<br />" +
                                   "Permit From: " + data.PermitFrom + "<br />" +
                                   "Permit To: " + data.PermitTo + "<br />" +
                                   "Registration Status: " + data.RegistrationStatus 
                );
});
```

Then on your Ajax Call you need to make this change as well:

```
function MakeAJAXCall(regId, callback)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text json",
            url: "/Secure/CustomerSummary.aspx/GetRegistration",
            data: "{ regId: \"" + regId + "\" }",

            success: function (msg) {                
                data = msg.d;  
                callback(data); //<--- You callback function is called here              
            },

            error: function (xOptions, textStatus)
            {                
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(xOptions);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First A in Ajax is for asynchronous. It means your call will run in the background and that is why you use callbacks. When your call completed with success/error, say 10 seconds later, correct function is called. In the meanwhile, you other code that sets up and creates a result also runs, most likely before any answers received from ajax query. As @Dalorzo suggested, wrap your result dialog code in a callback, so your code will run **after** results received.